# What SQL Server Datatype Should I Use To Store A Byte[]

Tags: sql-server, types

I want to store an array of bytes in my SQL Server. What datatype, or pre INSERT manipulation would you suggest to store these?

I wouldn't expect these `byte[]` to exceed 1024 in length.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`varbinary(1024)` is what you're looking for.

There are three types in SQL Server for binary value storage:

`binary(n)` for fixed-length binary data of length `n`. Length can be `1` to `8000`.
`varbinary(n)` for variable-length binary data maximum length `n`. Maximum length can be `1` to `8000`.
Above types will be stored in the row data itself.
`varbinary(max)` which is used to store large binary values (BLOBs) up to 2GB. The actual value is stored in a separate location if it's larger than 8000 bytes and just a pointer is stored in the row itself. This type is available since SQL Server 2005.

`image` data type was used to store BLOBs prior to SQL Server 2005. It's deprecated in favor of `varbinary(max)`. The storage location for `image` is always outside data row.

Comment: in your last sentence, do you mean the behavior of `image` is the same as `varbinary(max)` that are over 8k bytes?